# ListView - Start activity if clicked on ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

My ListView gets filles by this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/projectImage"
            android:maxHeight="70dp"
            android:maxWidth="70dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/projectTitle"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="projecttitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/projectTopic"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="projectTopic"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/projectdeadline"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="projectdeadline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="projectTaskCount"
                    android:id="@+id/projectTaskCount"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It contains one `ImageView` and three `TextView`s.
If I click on the `ImageView` I want to start my `Activity` Example1, else open next `Activity` WiFi.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent in = new Intent(this, WiFi.class);

    in.putExtra("projectFileNamesMap", projectFileNamesMap.get(position));
    in.putExtra("position", position);
    in.putExtra("sessionId", sessionId);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

How can I solve my Problem?

Summarized:
If I click on `ImageView` open Example1 Activity.
If elsewhere clicked, then open WiFi Activity.

Hope everybody can understand this.

Kind Regards!

Comment: Setup a Touch Listener and start your required activity.

Comment: don't use onItemClick....else use imageview onclick from your adapter

Comment: Implement OnClickListener on the ImageView in the getView method inside your custom adapter.

Comment: I implementet the onclicklistener for my imageview in my custom adapter but if i click on the imageview it start both activities.

Comment: @miteshpithadiya you gave me the right idea!!!! thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use image.setOnclickListener and view.setOnItemCLickListener inside getView method to perform click on image view and whole view.

Answer (score 1):

First set your image:

```
android:clickable="true" //setOnClickListener makes a view clickable if it doesn't have that as a default but use it anyway.
```

then:

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.v(TAG, " click");         
   }        
});
```

pls tell me if this works

Answer (score 1):

Write OnClickListener for ImageView when creating a new Instance for each ImageView elements for the listView in the Adapter's getView method

Also make sure before you addView's to the Linearlayout you set appropriate LayoutParams.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txtOne, txtTwo, txtThree;
        ImageView iv;
        LinearLayout layout;

        if(convertView == null){
            layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            txtOne = new TextView(context);
            txtTwo = new TextView(context);
            txtThree = new TextView(context);
            iv = new ImageView(context);
        } else{
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            txtOne = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
            txtTwo = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
            txtThree = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
            iv = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(0);
        }
        layout.addView(txtOne);
        layout.addView(txtTwo);
        layout.addView(txtThree);
        layout.addView(iv);

        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Do your handling here
            }
        });
```

}

Comment: This is a good answer. If you want to implemet the listener in the activity ,you can pass custom listener object to adapter and you can set this adapter to a view.